# Make IdeaVim use IDE shortcuts in insert mode but VIM key map in normal mode

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

I'm new to vim and still learning it but i found the shortcuts in IntelliJ are quite easy to use.

Eg: `Ctrl + b` for Go to declaration, `Ctrl + q` Show doc

I often check docs while I'm writing code and I'd like to keep the shortcuts available in `insert mode`(since vim key map seems mostly work with `normal mode`).

I read online and saw methods about adding custom key mapping for vim. Besides that, Is there anyway that I can keep all IDE shortcuts in `insert mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently each shortcut like `Ctrl+B` is handled by either the Vim emulation or the IDE. See [the docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#installation) on how to choose the handler for a shortcut.

Feel free to file a feature request [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM) for handling Vim commands only the normal mode.